# How to stop Visual Studio from setting a new project to build in all configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a solution with a large number of solution level build configurations. Whenever I add a project to this solution, Visual stuido changes all of my configurations to build the new project. Is there a way to stop VS from doing this, or am I stuck reconstructing all my build configurations every time I add a new project to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any solution within visual studio but you could do it by hand rather easily. Project files are simply xml files and solution files are text-based as well (and rather simple structured).

If you know how to handle MSBuild files (i.e. project files) you can even simplify them if you have many configurations.

This is the msdn article for MSBuild:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I was hoping for a solution within visual studio. I am aware that I could manually edit the solution file, but this is no better than simply managing the configurations with the configuration manager provided in visual studio.

Comment: I have been struggling with that too but I have not found any in-built solution. But I find doing it manually much easier than going through every single configuration in the config manager. It's just copy/paste really.